# DownloadManager Request not starting when wifi hotspot enabled

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-download-manager

I have a device which is running a webserver.
The device connects to my Android 10 smartphone using its wifi hotspot.
In my app I'm displaying the device its webpages in a webview.
I'm trying to download a file from the webview to my smartphone:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
     if (url.endsWith(".ext")) {
         try {
             Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
             DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
             request.setDescription("Demo .ext file");
             request.setTitle("Demo.ext");
             request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
             request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
             request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Demo.ext");
             DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
             manager.enqueue(request);
```

The download URL would be for example "http://192.168.43.1/data/Demo.ext".

Unfortunately, the download does not start while my smartphone has hotspot enabled.
As soon as I disable the hotspot and connect to a wifi network (or enable data), the download starts.
However, the download will not succeed since the file has to be downloaded from the device which obviously isn't connected anymore when hotspot is disabled.

When accessing my device with Google Chrome instead of my app, the download will work.

Is there a way to start the download using the webview in my app?

Comment: `192.168.43.1` That looks like the ip of your hotspot. Not of the device that is running the webserver.

Comment: `Is there a way to start the download using the webview in my app?` You are not using a WebView to download but the DownloadManager.

Comment: Android 10? usesClearTextTraffic enabled? request legacy external storage enabled?

Comment: Yes, userClearTextTraffic and request legacy external storage are enabled in my manifest file.
All http requests to the device are working, except the download is not starting.
When using Chrome instead of my app, the download starts immediately.

Comment: Please react to my first comment.

Comment: It was an example. I can confirm that I'm using the right IP since all other pages (except for the download) are working/resolving.

Comment: @Dieter27 Did you find any solution?

Comment: @dif_jeff Yes but not by using the DownloadManager class. Instead of using DownloadManager, I switched to ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument(), which returns a content URI. Then I download and save the file with an InputStream and OutputStream to that content URI.